# Move files based on name (with an extra complication)

Tags: powershell

I´ve seen a couple of topics showing how to move files based on their names. I have an extra issue with this matter.
I have a bunch of video files, based on tv series with the
`name of the series + season + episode number`
For example: `Breaking.Bad.s01e03`
And my files are organized like:

```
d:\series\breaking bad\season01
d:\series\breaking bad\season02
d:\series\breaking bad\season03
...
etc
```

What I need is a script that checks for series name+season and moves them to it's corresponding folder.
Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: IMO this question better suits to [SU] where I've answered a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1330038/filename-extract-powershell) myself

Answer (score 1):

The OP needs this to be case-insensitive - and the `.Replace()` method is not. Changed to use the `-replace` operator instead.

```
$FileName = 'Breaking.Bad.S01e03'

$Series = $FileName.Substring(0, $FileName.LastIndexOf('.')).Replace('.', '_')
# disabled the initial version since the OP now needs case-insensitive replacement
#$Season = $FileName.Split('.')[2].Split('e')[0].Replace('s', 'Season')
$Season = $FileName.Split('.')[2].Split('e')[0] -replace 's', 'Season'

$Series
$Season
```

output ...

```
Breaking_Bad
Season01
```

I will leave to you the process of building a path from the above AND how to move files. [*grin*] here's a pair of hints ...

```
Get-Help Join-Path
Get-Help Move-Item
```

---

The OP has changed the entire format of the files, so this is a version that works with that format. No other formats were given, so no other formats were coded for.

```
# fake reading in filenames
#    in real life, use Get-ChildItem
$FileList = @(
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Breaking.Bad.s02E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Breaking.Bad.S03e01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Breaking.Bad.s04e01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi'
    )

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $SeriesName = ($FL_Item.BaseName -split '\.s\d')[0].Replace('.', '_')
    $SE_Info = $FL_Item.BaseName.Split('.')[-3] -split 'e'

    $Season = $SE_Info[0] -replace 's', 'Season'
    $Episode = 'Episode{0}' -f $SE_Info[1]

    $SeriesName
    $Season
    $Episode
    ''
    }
```

output ...

```
Breaking_Bad
Season01
Episode01

Breaking_Bad
Season02
Episode01

Breaking_Bad
Season03
Episode01

Breaking_Bad
Season04
Episode01
```

---

Again, I will refer you to `Join-Path`, New-Item, and `Move-Item` for creating the destination paths and moving the files.

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I add a check if instead of s the file has S? For example, the file name is Breaking.Bad.S01E02
An another thing, how do I run this for a bunch of files in a folder and subfolders?

Comment: [1] lower/upper case - powershell is case _insensitive_ by default in most situations. that is not true for the `.Replace()` method. so use the `-replace` operator since it uses case-insensitive regex. the case-sensitive version is `-creplace`. ///// i will go back to the answer and add a case-insensitive version right quick ...

Comment: Ok, so this is working

`code $FileName = 'Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi'

$Series = $FileName.Substring(0, $FileName.LastIndexOf('.S')).Replace('.', ' ')
$Season = $FileName.Split('.')[2].Split('E')[0].Replace('S', 'Season ')

$Series
$Season

$SeriesDirectory = Join-Path -Path "$Series" -ChildPath "$Season"
$SeriesDirectory

$MoverArchivo = move-item -path $FileName -destination e:\series\$SeriesDirectory
$MoverArchivo`

Comment: @MarianoCandial - [2] to run this against a folder of files, use `Get-ChildItem` to get the files, and then `foreach` to loop thru them. once you have the new name, use `Move-Item` to move the files.

Comment: Great! Got the insensitive, but now the same issue happends with split, is there a insensitive for that?

Comment: I wrote this, but it's not working

`$FileName = 'Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi'

$Count1 = 2
$Count2 = 0
$Separator1 = '.'
$Separator2 = 'e'
$Season = $FileName -split $Separator1,$Count1,"SimpleMatch" -split $Separator2,$Count2,"SimpleMatch" -replace 's', 'Season '`

Comment: @MarianoCandial - next time, PLEASE give folks all the info needed. [*grin*] ///// the `-split` operator is case-insensitive.

Comment: @MarianoCandial - you have given a TOTALLY different file name format. [*sigh ...*] is that the real format this time? will there be any other formats? it's absolutely necessary that the code handle all the variants ... and you have shown two so far. what file name variants will be seen?

Comment: The season and episode number might come as S01.E01, or S01E01 s01e01 s01.e01

Comment: @MarianoCandial - please make a NEW question. include in that the FULL DETAILS of the various file names. i am too frustrated to do anything more here.